# Yes/No loop in C

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I just don't understand why this Yes/No loop will not work.  Any suggestions?  Given the input is "Y".  I just want it to run the loop, then ask for Y or N again.  If Y, print success, if N, print a good bye statement. What's the reason?

```
int main(){
    char answer;
    printf("\nWould you like to play? Enter Y or N: \n", answer);
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    printf("\n answer is %c");
    while (answer == 'Y'){
        printf("Success!");

        printf("\nDo you want to play again? Y or N: \n");
        scanf("%c", &answer);
    }
    printf("GoodBye!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what happens when you run it?

Comment: you know when it asks you the question you have to type:   Y<Enter>   it doesn't work on keypress

Comment: I will add "not work" means it executes the whole program and prints goodbye without giving me the chance to answer "Y" or "N" again and execute the loop again.

Comment: @Keith, I didnt know tht

Comment: type YY<ENTER>  and it will do what you expect

Comment: (Not related to your question) Fix your 2nd `printf()`. There you expect a char with "%c", but the parameter `answer` is missing.

Comment: also your frist printf has answer as a parameter, but you don't use it, so remove it

Comment: You should really check that `scanf()` is returning something.  If the user types EOF, your program probably won't terminate (once you've fixed the problem with not reading/ignoring newlines and other white space.

Comment: what am I supposed to make of "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed the various issues

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(){
char answer;
printf("\nWould you like to play? Enter Y or N: \n");
scanf(" %c", &answer);
printf("\n answer is %c\n", answer);
while (answer == 'Y'){

printf("Success!");

printf("\nDo you want to play again? Y or N: \n");

scanf(" %c", &answer);
printf("\n answer is %c\n", answer);

}
printf("GoodBye!");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!  You got it perfect.  Ive researched a while for this straight simple answer everywhere and you answered it perfectly.  That damn extra space before the %c.  Like I told Hao, I tried to upvote but aint got the rep yet.  Sorry.  Great response though!

Comment: you should have the rep now, and you should be able to accept the answer

Comment: what am I supposed to make of "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’" when I compile?  Program still works perfect, but are these a worry?

Comment: at the top,  add the line #include <stdio.h>

Comment: you will also likely need stdlib.h and string.h as you go forward....  but basically that warning says we came across printf and guessed that it is a function using our default guess, but then when we linked it, we found the real function and its different, but because I'm C, I'll just let you do that and for the most it will work out, until it doesn't, then you'll have a bug thats really hard to find, especially if you are a noob

Answer (score 16):

Change the second `scanf` to:

```
scanf(" %c", &answer);
//     ^
```

The problem is, when you enter Y and press ENTER, the new line is still in the input buffer, adding a space before `%c` could consume it.

Comment: You were right on man!  I tried to upvote your answer but I need a rep of 15.  lol, sorry. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: When I have a loop of scanf, is it always a good idea adding a blank  before `% `?

Comment: @LidongGuo It depends. In most situations, it's better to avoid using `scanf` at all, use `fgets` to get the whole line and `sscanf` to get the contents.

Comment: can fgets get a single char?

Comment: @GetKnighted It can only get the whole line, but you can then use `sscanf` to get the single char. The potential problem of `scanf` is, the user may not input what you expect him to input, which may cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the repetition in your code a bit, and check the result of `scanf()` (as you should) by writing:

```
int main(void)
{
    char answer;
    printf("Would you like to play? Enter Y or N: ");
    while (scanf(" %c", &answer) == 1 && answer == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Answer is %c\n", answer);
        printf("Success!\n");
        printf("Do you want to play again? Y or N: ");
    }
    printf("GoodBye!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The first `printf()` lost the unused argument `answer`; the second `printf()` collected the necessary second argument, `answer`.  Except for prompts, it is generally best to end printing operations with a newline (rather than use a newline at the start).  Prompts will generally be flushed by the C library before the input from `stdin` is read, so you don't need the newline at the end of those.

Since `printf()` returns the number of characters it prints, you can use it in conditions too:

```
int main(void)
{
    char answer;
    printf("Would you like to play? Enter Y or N: ");
    while (scanf(" %c", &answer) == 1 &&
           printf("Answer is %c\n", answer) > 0 &&
           answer == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Success!\n");
        printf("Do you want to play again? Y or N: ");
    }
    printf("GoodBye!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This always echoes the answer, even if the answer was not `Y` and the loop exits.

Comment: I F****** love the tips man!!  Like I said, Im a total noob.  Just trying to get my feet wet. Always love a great suggestion!  Thanks bro!