# getchar is not waiting for user input

Tags: c, getchar

Second getchar function is not waiting for user input. Could not figure out what is missing in the following code

```
char ch = 'n';
bool status = false;

printf("%s", "Some text1\n");
ch = getchar();

if ((ch == 'Y') || (ch == 'y'))
{
    status = true;
}

if(status)
{
    printf("%s", "Some text2\n");
    ch = getchar();

    if ((ch == 'Y') || (ch == 'y'))
    {
        status = eNoError;
    }
}
```

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653884/getchar-does-not-stop-when-using-scanf

Comment: @Jeyaram: Your link solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @impulse Note: `getchar()` returns an `int`. So, `ch` should be an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

That's because of a newline character.

When you enter first `'Y'`, you actually enter a string like `"Y\n"`.

First `getchar()` reads `'Y'`, and `'\n'` sits in a buffer.
So the second `getchar()` gets that `'\n'` character.

Comment: ok. do I need another getchar() to get input? or is there any better way to handle this

Comment: I believe the simplest way to overcome this would be to use `scanf(" %c", &c)`, as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/18627241/371970

Comment: This check need to be there after each getchar.do {
    c = getchar();
}while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to necro this post but I'm posting this in case anyone else runs into this problem and wants a better answer. The easiest way around this is to flush the input somewhere between the first getchar and the second:

```
ch = getchar();
fflush(stdin); // can be anywhere in between the getchar() calls
ch = getchar();
```

Hopefully this helps someone out moving forward