# scanf not working on invalid input

Tags: c, debugging, scanf, stdin

On a character input in the first `scanf()`, the second one doesn't run. `getchar()` isn't working either for Try Again input. It skips to take input for  **Would you like to play again? (Y/N)?** It seems that `your_choice` is supposed to take the character and check it afterward but the character is actually being taken by `ch`. What is causing it to work like this and how to resolve the issue. I've tried re-initializing the variables but doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void choice(int);

int main() {
    char ch;
    int random, your_choice;

    do {
        srand(time(NULL));
        system("cls");
        printf("** 0 is for Rock **\n");
        printf("** 1 is for Scissors **\n");
        printf("** 2 is for Lizard **\n");
        printf("** 3 is for Paper **\n");
        printf("** 4 is for Spock **\n");

        printf("\nEnter your choice here:");
        scanf("%d", &your_choice);

        random = rand() % 5; //random number between 0 & 4
        if ((your_choice >= 0) && (your_choice <= 4)) {
            //choice printer omitted for this post

            if ((random == ((your_choice + 1) % 5)) || (random == ((your_choice + 2) % 5)))
                printf("\n\n... and you win!!!\n");
            else if ((random == ((your_choice + 3) % 5)) || (random == ((your_choice + 4) % 5)))
                printf("\n\n... and you lose!!!\n");
            else if (random == your_choice)
                printf("\n\nUnfortunately, it's a tie!\n");
        } else
            printf("\nWell, this is wrong! Try again with a number from 0 to 4!!\n");

        printf("\nWould you like to play again? (Y/N)?: ");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);

    } while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for starters, take away your space before the `%c` in the second `scanf`

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`. If there is parse error, the invalid input is left in the input buffer, so you have to get rid of it before trying to `scanf` the same data again. If you ignore return value of `scanf` and don't react to its parse errors, you usually end up with program which behaves totally unexpectedly on invalid input.

Comment: @hyde upon printing ch, it gives the value entered in choice.

Comment: Maybe duplicate with [Yes/No loop in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627163/yes-no-loop-in-c)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Did you change `scanf("%c", &ch);` to `scanf(" %c", &ch);` before posting?

Comment: @jnbbender: absolutely not! the space tells `scanf()` to ignore pending spaces, which is necessary to skip the newline character still present in the standard input buffer after the first input was read.

Comment: @nAiN where does it print `ch`?

Comment: In a test, I printed the character in ch and it was the same as that entered in choice (the invalid one)

Comment: This actually works fine for me.

Comment: @nAiN  This problem is harder to solve because it does not contain the _input used_.  "getchar() isn't working either. " is insufficient detail.  Post the code (good, you did that), the input used, results seen and results expected.  You will receive better responses, less chatter and more up-votes.

Comment: @cdcdcd try it with an invalid input.

Comment: put `srand` outside of the loop. [srand() — why call it only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714). [How does calling srand more than once affect the quality of randomness?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27209282/995714)

Comment: I'm afraid that won't be the real concern here

Comment: @nAiN: That's exactly how it should be. You asked the first `scanf` to read `%d`. It will refuse to read any invalid characters, leaving them for your second `scanf`. Your expectations like "`your_choice` is supposed to take the character and check it afterward" are completely unfounded. `scanf` doesn't work that way.

Comment: @nAiM this is not my finest moment on stack overflow. But you're right again. Methinks a more sophisticated routine or just use a simple int 0/1 rather than a char.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the user enters characters that cannot be converted to a number, `scanf("%d", &your_choice);` returns 0 and `your_choice` is left unmodified, so it is uninitialized.  The behavior is undefined.

You should test for this and skip the offending input this way:

```
    if (scanf("%d", &your_choice) != 1) {
        int c;
        /* read and ignore the rest of the line */
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
        if (c == EOF) {
            /* premature end of file */
            return 1;
        }
        your_choice = -1;
    }
```

Explanation:

- `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions. If the user types a number, it is converted and stored into `your_choice` and `scanf()` returns 1, if the user enters something that is not a number, such as `AA`, `scanf()` leaves the offending input in the standard input buffer and returns 0, finally if the end of file is reached (the user types ^Z enter in windows or ^D in unix), `scanf()` returns `EOF`.
- if the input was not converted to a number, we enter the body of the `if` statement: input is consumed one byte at a time with `getchar()`, until either the end of file or a linefeed is read.
- if `getchar()` returned `EOF`, we have read the entire input stream, no need to prompt the user for more input, you might want to output an error message before returning an error code.
- otherwise, set `your_choice` to `-1`, an invalid value so the read of the code complains and prompts for further input.

Reading and discarding the offending input is necessary: if you do not do that, the next input statement `scanf(" %c", &ch);` would read the first character of the offending input instead of waiting for user input in response to the `Would you like to play again? (Y/N)?:` prompt.  This is the explanation for the behavior you observe.

Comment: What exactly `return 1;` does?

Comment: It exits from `main` and ends the program. The return value can be caught by (in Windows) a batch file that might have called your program, by checking `errorlevel`.

Comment: @nAiN it is easier to manage faulty inputs if you first input to a string with `fgets` and then apply `sscanf` to that string (checking the return value from those functions). If the input was incorrect, you just dump that line and try again.

Comment: @nAiN: Using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` is a good suggestion. I wish C tutorials would take this approach more often.