# C Programming: input buffer unintentionally cleared after scanf?

Tags: c, input, io, scanf, user-input

I'm attempting to get an input of numbers via the format:

```
c1 c2 [c1 amount of integers separated by white space] [c2 amount of integers separated by white space]
```

And assigning the numbers in different places based on whether they are in the c1 segment, or c2 segment.

This means I have to read and use `c1` and `c2` as variables in a for loop after scanning the first two values.

Here's my code:

```
scanf("%d %d ", &np, &nm); // np and nm are c1 and c2

for (j = 0; j < np; j++)
{
    scanf("%d ", &tempvalue);
    // assign tempvalue to somewhere via a function
}
for (j = 0; j < nm; j++)
{
    scanf("%d ", &tempvalue);
    // assign tempvalue elsewhere via a function
}
```

But for whatever reason, debugging with print statements show that after the first assignment for `c1`, the program is asking for an input again (the input buffer cleared??) Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: Well, after `scanf("%d %d ", &np, &nm)`, it will ask for input again with `scanf("%d ", &tempvalue)`, right? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Owen no, everything has to be put in one line. so for example: 1 1 1 1, or 1 2 1 1 2, 3 2 1 1 1 2 2, the first two numbers dictate how many integers will follow

Comment: @anastaciu it is the required input format of the problem im trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` specifier automatically discards blank spaces between the inputed numbers, remove the *all* the spaces from `scanf` specifier, they are not needed and just mess up your input, especially the ones at the end.

Note that for a more robust code you should verify the return value of `scanf`, ***i.e.*** if it maches the number of values  to be read, and guard against invalid inputs ***i.e.*** non-digit inputs.

Here is a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552127/6865932

Ideally you would use `fgets` to get the input and `sscanf` or `strtol` to parse, if it conforms with your specs.